# How can I create img-button on my SharePoint WebPage

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I created some buttons on my page, and now want to add full size image on button.

```
<table>
    <tr>
            <th>
                    <button type="button1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="openInDialog()">
                    <span align="right" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Finance & BD&L
                    </button>
            </th>

            <th>
                    <button type="button1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="openInDialog2()">
                    <span align="right" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Market Access​
                    </button>
            </th>   
            <th>
                    <button type="button1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="openInDialog3()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Business Excellence & Commercial operations 
                    </button>
            </th>


            <th>
                    <button type="button1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="openInDialog4()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Legal & Compliance
                    </button>
            </th>   

    <tr>
            <th>
                    <button type="button1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="openInDialog5()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Oncology BU
                    </button>
            </th>


            <th>
                    <button type="button1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="openInDialog6()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Hematology BU
                    </button>
            </th>

            <th>
                    <button type="button1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="openInDialog7()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></span> Medical
                    </button>
            </th>

            <th>
                    <button type="button1" class="btn btn-default" onclick="openInDialog8()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" ></span> HR
                    </button>
            </th>
    </tr>
```

This is my HTML code button. I was loaded images to "Documents" page on my site and copy url link in code, but Content Editor still doesnt see this image. I think, that my problem in url, but how i can fix this?

this is css code

```
    button [type="button1"] {
            margin-top: 5px;
            marring-left: 5px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 260px; 
            height: 155px;
            background: url('https://share.novartis.net/sites/ruphoncology/Shared%20Documents/00218_300dpi_RGB.jpg');
    }
```

But this dosent work

Comment: Read this article. It may help you
https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SPLinksImage.htm

Comment: Error was in my own code, but friend below could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your css code should be like this,

```
[type=button1] {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 155px;
    background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/60597/dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }
```

I have used some another image. You replace your own.